# Ignore symbols in SORT METHOD

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, symbols

So I'm trying to sort a string array(global variable), although I'm able to ignore the case sensitivity, I need help in ignoring the symbols that come before the first alphabet, e.g. 
~abc, etc..

```
public void sort()
{   
    int n = myArray.length;
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n-i-1; j++){
            if((myArray[j+1]).compareToIgnoreCase(myArray[j])<0){
                String temp = myArray[j];
                myArray[j] = myArray[j+1];
                myArray[j+1] = temp;
                //toLower
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can write a simple method to transform the string by extracting only alphabets or can use regex

Comment: If you sort letter from English alphabet you can use very simple regular expression. Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/DfbeSK/1

Answer (score 1):

You can drop all the special characters and do a sort.

```
// Drop all special characters
List<String> collect = Arrays.asList(myArray).stream().map(e -> e.replaceAll("[YourSpeciallCharacterss]", "")).collect(Collectors.toList());
//sort the list
collect.sort(String::compareTo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove control characters by replacing all characters which match:

`\p{Cntrl}` - A control character: `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]`

Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("\u0001" + "B", "\u0002" + "AAA", "\u0003" + "AB");
    System.out.println("With control characters: " + list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    Pattern removeControl = Pattern.compile("\\p{Cntrl}");
    List<String> sorted = list.stream().map(s -> removeControl.matcher(s)
        .replaceAll("")).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("No control characters: " + sorted);
}
```

This prints out:

```
With control characters: [B, AAA, AB]
No control characters: [AAA, AB, B]
```

Answer (score -1):

ok, so i came up with this code. It compiles but gets stuck in an endless loop while running; however, when i don't ignore the symbols, it does run (takes 18 seconds to sort and write, maybe because there r 30,000 words..) otherwise, it gets stuck in an endless loop

class IO{

```
String[] myArray = new String[30000];

public void read()
{

    try {
        Scanner myLocal = new Scanner( new File("dictionary.txt"));  
        while (myLocal.hasNextLine()){

                for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
                String a = myLocal.nextLine();
                myArray[i] = a;

            }
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void sort()
{   
    int n = myArray.length;
    String myIgnore = "[^a-zA-Z]+";  // alpha only
    String word1 = "";
    String word2 = "";

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<n-i; j++){ 
        word1 = myArray[j-1].replaceAll(myIgnore,"");
        word2 = myArray[j].replaceAll(myIgnore,"");
        if (word1.compareTo(word2)>0){





    String temp = word1;
    word1=word2;
    word2=temp;



            }

        }


    } 



}

public void write()
{
    try{
        PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(new File("myIgnoreNew.txt"));
        for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
            writer.println(myArray[i] + "\n");
            }
            writer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}
```

}